# 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Currently i am working on django with postgresql (locally and on heroku). I many data in my locally installed postgresql almost (5000 rows). i am trying to push my local db to heroku.
What i have done so far is.
1)  `heroku pg:push postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:8000/ DATABASE --app djangoshopnroar`
after this command, it give me error to run command

```
heroku pg:reset
```

after this command. data from heroku get deleted. again i run the first command e.g

```
heroku pg:push postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:8000/ DATABASE --app djangoshopnroar
```

where as, **djangoshopnroar** is my app on heroku where postgresql is placed. 
but when i run this command again, i initially received this message "'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?"

can anybody tell me where i am wrong?
how can i push my local data from postgree to postgree on heroku?

i will be very thankful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: You haven't shown any use of `env` in the commands you've posted. Please show the full error log. `env` is a Unix command, and from the error you're clearly using Windows, but we can't help without seeing the context.

Comment: i am not using env command. i have just used only these command which i posted here. and you are right, i am using windows

Comment: Yes, I know. So you need to show the full list of things you did do, along with the full error messages.